# Get system default menu popup alignment/direction

Tags: winapi

I'd like to find out what the default menu popup alignment/direction is. When you use the main menu in an application or use a context popup menu it opens up to the right, centered or to the left - depending on the Windows version, some custom registry settings or left/right-hand options.

There must be a way to get that information using some Windows API (instead of building a complex function for different Windows versions / preferences / registry modifications etc.).

I need this to apply that information to some custom elements in my application that I want to open into the same direction as all other menus on that system. This is a Delphi application, but if it's an API call then I'd be happy about a solution in a language of your choice.

Comment: The easiest way to get the default menu behavior is probably to use a menu. Menus can be customized to display just about anything.

Comment: SPI_GETMENUDROPALIGNMENT is what you want.

Comment: Further to Raymond's comment, the actual API function is `SystemParametersInfo()`.

Comment: SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GetMenuDropAlignment, 0, @ res, 0); does the job. Thanks a lot!
@RaymondChen If you want you can create an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: You are welcome to write your own answer and accept it. I don't understand Delphi well, so you're in a better position to write the Delphi-compatible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of Raymond Chen and Jonathan Potter here's a function that does the trick:

```
function PopupMenusRightAligned(): Boolean;
var
  res: Integer;
begin
 SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GetMenuDropAlignment, 0, @res, 0);
 Result := res=0;
end;
```

API documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ms724947